# How do i login to Windows 10 after all services have started

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, services, autostart

I have a need to login to desktop after all services have started so essentially no service is running in the background after the desktop is loaded post login. How can i do this?

Comment: *no service is running in the background* ... This doesn't make sense. What's your end goal here?

Comment: *All* operating systems have services running in the background, whether you login or not.

Comment: I should say no service is started in a delayed fashion where its unknown when it would start post logon. I understand all the services that are started are running in the background

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: it's impossible

The long answer: there are three service start methods that can be defined: immediate, delayed, and triggered.

Immediate starts the service when the OS starts. These are for the services the OS requires immediately.

Delayed waits a predetermined period of time, usually 3 minutes, after the computer starts before the service is started. This is used for important services that DON'T have to be running right at the beginning. Delaying the start of these services allows for quicker OS load and snappier performance in general as the system is mostly settled down before this second set of services are started.

So, if you wait 5 minutes after turning the computer on before logging in, most services should be running.

But, triggered services will still run WHEN THEY ARE TRIGGERED, which could be by scheduled task, or on demand from some Helper app, or other things.

If I were to guess, I'd say you're concerned about performance, but I would suggest you're worried about the wrong thing and looking in the wrong place for solutions to that. Leave the services alone unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: I am not concerned about the performance from a users perspective. I am running tests to profile our source make sure there is no regression in utilization. If there is any service running in the background when i am running this test we end up producing noise. I want to be able to make sure theres no major background activity while i run the test